# How to concatenate multiple sql rows into one row

Tags: sql

I have this output from query :

```
Select hostname,support1,support2 From hostnames where hostname in ('C')

C | NULL |  NULL 
C | NULL |  B 
C | A | NULL  
C | A | B
```

As you see there is `NULL | B` and `A | NULL`.
I need the output to be :

```
C | A | B
```

(to combine the two rows into one row ) 
How to do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
Select hostname, max(support1) as support1, max(support2) as support2
From hostnames
where hostname in ('C') 
group by hostname;
```

Comment: @Ayakhateb . . . I don't know what your comment means.  The syntax looks correct.